# How to align icons with single and multiple lines

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have the following HTML which is created by the [Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/) Menu Manager, Which means I cannot easily adapt this. So I need to have a way to work with it. Please don't suggest changing the way it is built up.

So here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Short Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Short Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Long Link That is Longer</a></li>  
</ul>
```

Obviously there are links there and no `#` but for the purpose of this question not necessary.

This is combined with this CSS:

```
ul {
  width:300px;
}
li {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #666;
}
i.fa {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Creating this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hg20dhwe/

**The Problem**

When a certain menu item has more then two words or have two long words then the alignment of the text and icons go completely wrong. Please take a look at the fiddle and you can see immediately what I mean.

What can I do with CSS to make this always align correctly? And with correctly I mean looking good. As the alignment is obviously already working according to the rules of CSS but it looks ugly in this case.

Thanks everyone.

**EDIT:** A solution that works with older browsers is preferred.

**Update**

New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgdda4zt/

New fiddle with max width set: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgdda4zt/1/

**Look at it in a small screen width otherwise you won't see the issue. The menu is normally 350px width but this is done by the grid system and not hardcoded into the menu. Or open the 2nd fiddle link**

This has a more accurate representation from the Joomla structure. Again there are no real links but that does not matter. I believe all styling that is involved is now part of the fiddle.

For everyone who already posted a reply, comment, solution thank you very much for your effort and I am sorry for not supplying the right tools (good fiddle).

Comment: Do you need to target legacy browsers?

Comment: @LarsBeck Yes that would be preferred.

Comment: @KarthikGanesan `pos.abs` breaks the entire menu and makes everything go within each other or over each other.

Comment: Updated your fiddle. Changed the display type to `display: table-cell` and added `vertical-align: top` to the `li` selector: https://jsfiddle.net/hg20dhwe/4/

Comment: @dward Tried your suggestion and I believe I already tried it 3 times as it gave the same result. Everything on one horizontal line. Not in the fiddle but in Joomla.

Comment: There could be another overriding style in your stylesheet. You might check your specificity levels of selectors, or encapsulate the css for this component so specificity wins. There are several ways to achieve your goal. With no other context other than your fiddle, my best guess would be specificity within your stylesheet if none of the answers here have helped.

Comment: @dward I am about to update the fiddle link to a better one more accurate with the end environement.

Comment: Could you update your answer with a mockup of what it should look like on desktop as well as smaller screen?

Comment: @YellowWebMonkey On desktop it should have 3 icons in a row, large tablets as well and then when smaller it goes to 2 in a row and eventually it comes down to 1 on very small screen. I intend to do this with media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting it and opted to go for the `Flex` properties. This resulted in the following CSS & HTML:

```css
.nav {max-width:350px;}
/* The above is only for this fiddle and not in Joomla */

.nav {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.nav.menu {
    text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
ul.nav.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  margin: 0 15px 10px 15px;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  line-height:20px;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.5s;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
  /* Use media queries for proper width settings */
  width: calc(33% - 30px);
  /* -30px because of the margin set above */
}
ul.nav.menu a {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: #666;
}
.nav > li > a {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #666;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.5s;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
}
i {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

/*I need to counter this fontawesome 'inline-block' part as in Joomla it does not use fontawesome but flaticon*/

.fa {display:block;font-size:2rem;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <ul class="nav menu">
  <li class="item-569">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home flaticon-iconname"></i> Short Link</a>
  </li>  
  <li class="item-586">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home flaticon-iconname"></i> Long Link that is longer</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item-587">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home flaticon-iconname"></i> Short Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item-588">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home flaticon-iconname"></i> Short Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item-589">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home flaticon-iconname"></i> Short Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item-590">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home flaticon-iconname"></i> Short Link</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

See it all in it's glory in the above code snippit or on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgdda4zt/6/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `display:flex;` on the `ul` tag

```
ul {
  width:300px;
  display: flex;
}
```

[**See jsfiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/hg20dhwe/1/)

Or you can also use `float:left;` on the `li` tags

```
li {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

[**See jsfiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/hg20dhwe/2/)

Comment: I tried it in Joomla and there it makes the entire menu go onto one line. I must say though in the Fiddle it works perfect.

Comment: @purple11111 How would you like it to be displayed ?

Comment: @purple11111 By "go onto one line," do you mean one vertical line?

Comment: @Chiller I want the icon to be above the text

Comment: @freginold No everything is in one horizontal line.

Comment: @purple11111 you should inpect the page and see if another css style is used and is overriding your css

Comment: @Chiller Just tried your solution 2 which is almost perfect. Now it only leaves big white spaces. The fiddle is not a perfect representation of the menu in Joomla. The menu in joomla has 3 columns what happens with solution 2 is that the first 2 columns are now sometimes empty but everything is aligned perfectly. :-) Now finding a way to make all spaces filled.

Comment: @purple11111 i think its because you are setting the width to 32% which is basically fixed

Answer (score 1):

As it is `displayed` as `inline-block`, so you could use `vertical-align` and `align` that, and using `nth-child selector` select `li` and then align, as below,

```
li:nth-child(3){
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```css
ul {
  width:300px;
}
li {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #666;
}
i.fa {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
ul > li:nth-child(3){
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Short Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Short Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Long Link That is Longer</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If the menu is 100 items long and the 37th item has long text do I need to fill in `child(37)`?

Comment: @purple11111 It's a very long menu :-) but yes you have to select and align as per this method. It's a one line styling just select that li and vertical align.

Comment: The thing is I want to set and forget because I can't be monitoring other people constantly to see if I have to change a digit. Otherwise it is a very good solution. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: That is exactly what I want. I am going to try this in Joomla. I assume I can just target the `i` instead of the `.fa`? Right?

Comment: So I added your code and getting the same result as it did with @chiller. I am going to upload a picture that shows what happens now. Should I define a height to the `a` element?

Comment: @purple11111 try aligning them using margin-bottom. Update - On recently posted fiddle by you in that add vertical-align:top - ul.nav.menu li

Comment: Just tried it with the new fiddle and I am adding the `margin-bottom` in the wrong part or it is not working: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgdda4zt/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to align icon and text as desired:

```
li {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 2.2rem;
}

.fa {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

UPDATE

```
li {
    display: table-cell;
}

a, .fa {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion it makes all icons go to the left of the text instead of staying above the text.

Comment: I didn't know it should be above, you might want to update your question with an image showing the wanted result EDIT: Got it, see my updated answer

Comment: Yeah I think that would be a wise thing to do.

Comment: Tried your update but the entire menu comes on a horizontal line after applying your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
li {
  width: 32%;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

but maybe you have some problem with this code. if use this code and have any problem with showing items around your list, comment here and i tell you what to do.

Comment: This question received so many answers and comments in a short amount of time I completely missed yours. Sorry about that. I did however tried your suggestion just now and this resulted in this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Lgdda4zt/4/
As you can see it brings up the same issue as with some other answers with `float:left;`

Comment: no problem :) . if you always have three items in each row, use this code too => "ul.nav.menu li:nth-child(3n+1) {clear: right;}". this will put items together correctly. only thing still have problem is the bottom line. this problem can just solve by adding some space character to smaller items.